# NSManagedObject passed to ViewController Does Reflect All Updates

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In my first view controller what I'm doing is setting up a NSManagedObjectContext from a UIMangedDocument in my viewDidLoad

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     NSURL *filePath = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
     filePath = [filePath URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Locations"];
     UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:filePath];

    //Create if it doesn't exist
     if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[filePath path]]) {

        //Async save
        [document saveToURL:filePath forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
             if (success) {
                self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
             }
         }];
    } else if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){

             //Open it, don't need to refetch stuff
             if (success) {
                self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
             }
         }];
     } else {
         self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
     }
 }
```

Then I insert a new object via a category method on my NSMangedObject subclass

```
[Location createLocationWithName:@"Maui" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Which just calls this code

```
Location *location = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Now the problem I'm having is when I segue to a new ViewController that has a public NSManagedObjectContext property and set it to this managedObjectContext in prepareForSegue the NSFetchedResultsController in the destinationViewController doesn't pick up this change right away. After I navigate back a forth a few times it eventually sees the Location Maui I created above. Any ideas why inserting a new Object into the managedObjectContext and then passing it to another view controller doesn't reflect that change?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you creation method contains the name you should at least also set this attribute (otherwise it will be lost). So second line of your creation implmentation:

```
location.name = name; // name is passed to the method
```

In order to ensure that the fetched results controller of the second view controller is updated immediately, you could set the `cacheName` to `nil` when creating the FRC. If you have lots of records and think you need the cache, you can do this in `viewWillAppear`:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

Comment: I have all that implemented but it's still not seeing my most recent insertion when transitioning to another view controller

Comment: See `reloadData` above. If still no luck, make sure you saved what you expect to see. Check in the physical database via `sqlite3` command line tool or Firefox's SQLiteManager.